# Facebook pixel + server "matching"

Tags: facebook

I want to do something that I thought would be very simple, but Facebook's docs are beyond confusing to me.

- A user (that is known to our servers) visits my site, and our Facebook pixel fires a simple page view event. Lets say the user has a UID of 1234 on our server
- Sometime later we use the facebook marketing api to send this information to Facebook: "User 1234 has made 9 purchases, totaling $1,500. Their most recent purchase was on January 12th, 2018"

My question is, can we somehow add this UID to the pixel event so that it can be used later in our api call?